# How to use async fulfillment for Actions on Google

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, actions-on-google

I'm trying to create a very simple voice app to query exchange rates by using **Google Conversational Actions**.

I use slots to get the *to* and *from* currencies. Then I try to call a web hook that in turn calls an API to get the rate between the two currencies.

First I tried defining the fulfillment function as `async` with `await request`, and then I tried `return await request`, but couldn't make the fulfillment function wait for the `GET` request to get back. Then I tried the code below using a `Promise` and now it times out. Not sure how to fix this.

```js
const { conversation } = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const request = require('request');

const app = conversation();

app.handle('get_exchange_rate', conv => {

    conv.session.params.rate = 0;

    let fromCcy = "EUR" //conv.session.params.currency_from_slot;
    let toCcy = "GBP" //conv.session.params.currency_to_slot;
    let url = `https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=${fromCcy}&symbols=${toCcy}`;

    let options = {
        json: true
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(url, options, (error, res, body) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                reject(error);
            } else if (res.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(body);
                conv.session.params.rate = body.rates[toCcy];
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
});

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**Note:** All the samples I've found so far in the docs are for trivial sync work, like returning a static message. I've not been able to find any examples on how to make this work with async work such as this.

**Update:** I'm doing this from the Google Conversational Actions console found at **Actions Console>Webhooks** and using the **Inline Cloud Functions** fulfillment type.

[image]

[image]

The timeout problem somehow went away —literally over night— and I was suddenly able to address the response in my conversation prompts as `$session.params.rate`.

It seems like there's something off with the propagation of changes from the Google Actions Console to Firebase. I also notice that switching from the **Develo** tab to the **Test** one takes an awful lot of time to load. There's this message `Your preview is being updated...` with a spinner that sometimes just takes forever. Sometimes it just kind of times out and asks me for the version I want to preview again. Then I try it a second time and it's instantly done. Not a very good DX yet.

Comment: I think you are along the right lines of returning a Promise from your app.handle() handler function.  You say when you tried it, the request times out ... I'd elaborate more on that in your post and investigate more on that area.

Comment: Are you sure that your URL is returning correctly? If you're using Firebase Functions you may need to upgrade your project to make external URL requests.

Comment: @NickFelker yes, I'm using Cloud Functions, but from the **Actions Console** inline editor. I'm not sure what you bean by "upgrade", but I have linked a billing account if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: I've updated the question with details to be more specific on the fulfillment. However, given that it did work for a bit, it would appear like it's not the code that wrong, but rather the integration between the Actions Console and Firebase Functions is faulty.

Comment: You should look at the [Firebase Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) plan and make sure you're on the right tier

Comment: Hi @Mig82 I believe what Nick is noting is that for api calls outside of Google APIs, the project needs to be at the Blaze Plan level ([Firebase Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)) and the default setup for the Actions Console is to Spark Plan. 


If that doesn't work, can you provide the error logs.

Answer (score 1):

I was hitting very similar issues to you using async/await.

I commented out all the async stuff, and gradually brought it all back in one at a time, and eventually it started working... *shrug*

I'm using node-fetch in my handler

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
/* plus your other regular includes */

app.handle('checkCurrentPrice', async conv => {

    const url = 'https://api....';

    let body = {"key" : "var"};
  
    const externalRes = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: {"Content-Type" : "application/json"},
    });
  
    const json = await externalRes.json();
});

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```